# Unknown ads when website opened on mobile

Tags: wordpress, malware

This is the 
[link to my website](http://kodicommunity.com/how-to-install-community-allsorts-on-kodi/).
Everything is fine when you open this website on desktop.
But if someone tries to open this link on mobile, there are links and ads that do not belong to me.
I am upset due to these ads.

Can anyone professional suggest me any remedy please?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your .htaccess file and then update permalinks again from settings->permalinks.

Comment: what will happen if i did that  ?

Comment: i try this but this was not useful for me. nothing happen still some one injecting my header.php and footer.php files.